# Expression for $\{B,e^A\}$ where $\{[B,A],A\}=0$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

I found this problem in a quantum field theory class, talking about fermionic modes. $B$ and $A$ are operators that obey anti-commutation relations. I have tried to solve it doing the following:
\begin{align*}
\{B,e^A\}=\{B,\sum_n \frac{A^n}{n!}\}=\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}\{B,A^n\}
\end{align*}
So the problem is about calculating $\{B,A^n\}$ under the condition $\{[B,A],A\}=0$.

Comment: I suppose that $[A,B]=AB-BA$ for operators. But what is $\{A,B\}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The anticommutator $AB+BA$.

Comment: You should explain this notation in the text, I think.  Also, what means that "$A$ and $B$ obey anti-commutation relations"? Which relations exactly?

Comment: @DietrichBurde [Some context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCR_and_CAR_algebras).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch:

We have $[B,\,A^2]=0$. Use $\{B,\,UV\}=[B,\,U]V+U\{B,\,V\}$, so $\{B,\,A^2V\}=A^2\{B,\,V\}$ and $\{B,\,A^{2n}V\}=A^{2n}\{B,\,V\}$, to show$$\{B,\,e^A\}=(\cosh A)\underbrace{2B}_{\{B,\,I\}}+(\operatorname{sinch}A)\{B,\,A\},$$provided we have the necessary convergence conditions to suitably manipulate infinite series.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I think there is a little mistake in the second term of the result, I've got $\sum_{n} \frac{A^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\{B,A\}$ and this series is different from the one corresponding to $\sinh A$ right?

Comment: @Armand Bear in mind $\operatorname{sinch}x:=\tfrac{\sinh x}{x}$ has an even series.

Comment: got it now. Thanks! :)